# Can't load UICollectionViewController Programatically by selecting cell

Tags: swift

I have been trying to segue to a UICollectionViewController when I select a cell in my table view in  a UIViewController with the following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let resultController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PhotosViewController") as? PhotosViewController {
        presentViewController(resultController, ANIMATED: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error saying UIStoryboard? does not have a member named 'instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier'

I have imported the UIKit. I am just not sure why it is not recognizing that member.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`storyboard` is an optional, you should use optional chaining to access it.

```
if let resultController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PhotosViewController") as? PhotosViewController {
    presentViewController(resultController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```